# Is there a way I can extract mutliple pieces of data from a multiple text file in python and save it as a row in a new .csv file?

Tags: python, data-science

Is there a way I can extract multiple pieces of data from a text file in python and save it as a row in a new .csv file? I need to do this for multiple input files and save the output as a single .csv file for all of the input files.

I have never used Python before so I am quite clueless. I have used matlab before and I know how I would do it in matlab if it was numbers (but unfortunately it is text which is why I am trying python). So to be clear I need a new line in the .csv output file for each "ID" in the input files. 
An example of the data is show below (2 separate files)

```
EXAMPLE DATA - FILE 1:
id,ARI201803290
version,2
info,visteam,COL
info,hometeam,ARI
info,site,PHO01
info,date,2018/03/29
id,ARI201803300
data,er,corbp001,2
version,2
info,visteam,COL
info,hometeam,ARI
info,site,PHO01
info,date,2018/03/30
data,er,delaj001,0



EXAMPLE DATA - FILE 2:
id,NYN201803290
version,2
info,visteam,SLN
info,hometeam,NYN
info,site,NYC20
info,usedh,false
info,date,2018/03/29
data,er,famij001,0
id,NYN201803310
version,2
info,visteam,SLN
info,hometeam,NYN
info,site,NYC20
info,date,2018/03/31
data,er,gselr001,0
```

I'm hoping to get the data in a .csv format with all the details from one "id" on 1 line. There are multiple "id's" per text file and there are multiple files. I want to repeat this process for multiple text files so the outputs are in the same .csv output file. I want the output to look as follows in the .csv file, with each piece of info as a new cell:

```
ARI201803290 COL ARI PHO01 2018/03/29 2
ARI201803300 COL ARI PHO01 2018/03/30 0
NYN201803290 SLN NYN NYC20 2018/03/29 0
NYN201803310 SLN NYN NYC20 2018/03/31 0
```

If I was doing it in matlab I'd use a for loop and if statement and say

```
j=1
k=1
for i=1:size(myMatrix, 1)

if file1(i;1)==id
output(k,1)=(i;2)
k=k+1

else if 
file1(i;1)==info && file1(i;1)==info
output(j,2)=(i;3) 
j=j+1
```

etc.....

However I obviously can't do this in matlab because I have comma separated text files, not a matrix. Does anyone have any suggestions how I can translate my idea to python code? Or any other suggestion. I am super new to python so willing to try anything that might work.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You need to open each file, then read content with readlines(). Next extract data with re library and save collected data into csv file

Answer (score 0):

python is very flexible and can do these jobs very easily,

there is a lot of csv tools/modules in python to handle pretty much all type of csv and excel files, however i prefer to handle a csv the same as a text file because csv is simply a text file with comma separated text, so simple is better than complicated

below is the code with comments to explain most of it, you can tweak it to match your needs exactly

```
import os

input_folder = 'myfolder/'  # path of folder containing the text files on your disk

# create a list with file names with their full paths using list comprehension
data_files = [os.path.join(input_folder, file) for file in os.listdir(input_folder)]

# open our csv file for writing
csv = open('myoutput.csv', 'w')  # better to open files with context manager like below but i am trying to show you different methods 

def write_to_csv(line):
    print(line)
    csv.write(line)

# loop thru your text files
for file in data_files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:  # use context manager to open files (best practice)
        buff = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()  # remove spaces and new lines
            line = line.split(',')  # split line to list of values
            if buff and line[0] == 'id':  # hit another 'id'
                write_to_csv(','.join(buff) + '\n')
                buff = []
            buff.append(line[-1]) # add the last word in line
        write_to_csv(','.join(buff) + '\n')


csv.close()  # must close any open file handles opened manually "no context manager i.e. no with"
```

output:

```
ARI201803290,2,COL,ARI,PHO01,2018/03/29,2
ARI201803300,2,COL,ARI,PHO01,2018/03/30,0
NYN201803290,2,SLN,NYN,NYC20,false,2018/03/29,0
NYN201803310,2,SLN,NYN,NYC20,2018/03/31,0
```